# Full Text Search and Role permissions

Tags: algorithm, architecture, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I am building a system where users have specific dynamic roles which give them access to some resources (i.e meta documents). Those documents META are indexed with Elastic Search.

I can do my queries without trouble.

Now I need to take roles into account:
If I add the roles allowed to see a given document while indexing docs I would then filter my query to match a particular role and return the results.

That is fine but if a role is changed I need to reindex all my documents.

If i do it dynamically on the server side on reception of the Elastic Search result It may work as well but will consume some CPU and bandwidth, plus it may be a problem with facet searches and pagination.

How would you solve such a problem?  What is the most suitable solution?

Comment: Interesting problem! I guess this is a specific case of the more general problem of performing queries which combine full-text search with relational aspects. Of course some relational databases do already support fast full-text search.

Comment: How often do roles change? How long does it take to index? Does re-indexing affect being able to search?

Comment: Actualy after I have seen that ES supports Bulk insert for faster indexing, reindexing will be a viable solution given than roles change not that often.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting proxy in front you Elastic Search, that will remove all unwanted results and do not care about the roles the Search at all ?